# How to interact with Smart Contracts (for test)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, remix

MY question is related to question 1 in:

[How to interact with a smart contract in practice (for free)? A bigger picture!](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23969/how-to-interact-with-a-smart-contract-in-practice-for-free-a-bigger-picture/23978?noredirect=1#comment25070_23978)

But the difference is that here I need more details.

---

I know I can compile a smart contract on [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/). I need to know how exactly I can interact with the smart contract.

Assume I have very simple smart contract; I have the following questions:

**Question 1**: How can  I write a transaction that calls (or interacts with) the contract?

**Question 2**: Is there any online service that allows me to do that (for free)?

---

I tried to get some free Ether from [here](http://www.ethereumfaucet.net/index.php), and I installed [metamask](http://www.ethereumfaucet.net/index.php), but my account shows zero Ether, so I couldn't get any Ether for the test.

Also, I don't know how to use the Ether for the test even if I have some.

Answer (score 3):

For Question 1:

You can try running a local test network using [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) which is initialized with 10 test accounts each filled with ~100ETH and a Mnemonic key that you can use with Metamask to gain access to them. Metamask lets you choose which network you are working with and you can select `testrpc` there, then say you forgot your password and add the mnemonic.

I've been using it with [truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle) to compile and migrate my contract to the test network, and building apps to interact with the contract using using [Vue.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue) and [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js). There's a good tutorial for getting started on [truffle's website](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/robust-smart-contracts-with-openzeppelin) or you can try my basic [vue.js + truffle starter repo](https://github.com/okwme/vue-truffle) too.

For Question 2:

You might be able to just use the ethereum.org [Browser Mist Wallet](https://wallet.ethereum.org). Go to the contracts section, deploy your compiled contract and you can access all of the functions public methods after selecting the contract and adding ABI info.